# A UITableview that occasionally loads itself with white space below the last record

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableview` that occasionally loads itself with white space below the last record. In the example with the screenshot below there are only 9 results returned and the table should end at that very last row. Instead there's quite a bit of scrolling white space within the table. If I then reload the table it's fine once again. It happens infrequently and I have no idea what what the problem might be.

It only happens when you move from this view controller to the detail view by selecting a table row. When you return to the first vc with the table the white space is there.

Here's a screenshot of what it looks like:

There are 9 results. I scrolled to the end of the 9 results (the bottom black rectangle is row number 9) and then the white space below that. You can see how much white space from the scroller.

[image]

Here's how I'm creating the cell:

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    tableCell *cell = (tableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {

    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"tableCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:204.0/255.0 green:56.0/255.0 blue:55.0/255.0 alpha:1];

    cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrowDisclosure.png"]];

    cell.descriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

    [cell.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Asap-Bold" size: 15.0f]];
    [cell.descriptionLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Asap-Regular" size: 10.0f]];
    [cell.priceDealLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Asap-Bold" size: 15.0f]];
    [cell.oldPriceDealLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Asap-Bold" size: 8.0f]];
    [cell.discountDealLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Asap-Bold" size: 12.0f]];

    [cell.ratingsNumberLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Asap-Regular" size: 9.0f]];
    [cell.amountLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Asap-Regular" size: 9.0f]];

}
```

It happens after a search is perform, a row is touched to move to a detail view and then on the return to the table view the white space is there.

I have this. It looks like I have the same frame code in for both keyboard methods. Could that be it?

```
    -(void) keyboardShown:(NSNotification *)note {

    CGRect keyboardFrame;
    [[[note userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue:&keyboardFrame];
    CGRect tableViewFrame = self.tableView.frame;
    tableViewFrame.size.height -= keyboardFrame.size.height;
    [self.tableView setFrame:tableViewFrame];

    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100,320, 333); // displaying results after keyboard shown.

}
-(void)keyboardHidden:(NSNotification *)note {

    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100,320, 333); // displaying results after keyboard is hidden. 

}
```

Comment: You should post some code so that people can help you.

Comment: How do you load the data in the tableview ? Do you modify the tableView's `contentSize` ?

Comment: What is the area in black? White area is the table view right?

Comment: @MeeraJPai yes the black is just the last row and 1/3 of the 8th row. the white is the rest of the tableview

Comment: can you provide the delegate methods you used for your tableview?

Comment: You're setting the table's frame twice in keyboardShown: - the 2nd time will undo what you've tried to achieve by shrinking it by the size of the keyboard

Comment: Can you post your cell creation code?

Comment: @SomaMan I added the cell creation code. thanks